# Adjusting microphone gain on a tablet

Tags: microphone

I've recently bought an onda tablet v919 3g air dual os windows 10 + android 4.4. I can call someone only from android because windows cant access the modem only for data. The only problem is that somewhere in the software the microphone's gain is set on max and when I initiate a phone call there is a very high background noise.

I've rooted the tablet and I now have access to all its files, but I cant find the place where I should change the code so I could get rid of "boot_autogain". Considering that I'm quite a newbie in apache I believe that I should modify the audio policy file, but I don't know where. From my research the files are the same as the ones from asus zenfone, with the only difference that onda putted on mic {custom configuration.

My question now is the gain is applied before HAL or after the mixing is done? Or where and how can I change the gain values?

And also, I know for sure that it's not a hardware problem considering that in windows I don't have this problem and I can modify the microphone's level and it works just fine with skype, messenger, recording...

[image: audio_policy.conf]

[image: asound.conf]

Comment: @cde I don't think it is on topic here as well. It is far beyond end-user level.

Comment: So is there anyone that can help me? I've asked the same question on stackoverflow and apparently they can't help me...

Comment: I thought only low level programming was off typically here. This is mid level, configuration changing. If it is off topic, then maybe a site like slate Droid, freak tab, or xda developers would help. Not sure how much support this manufacturers tablets get though.